# Obtain interpretations of functions and constants from a model

Tags: c#, z3

I'm writing a general function to get interpretation of a [FuncDecl](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_func_decl.html) from a model using [Z3's .NET API](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html).

Here is a simplified code fragment:

```
Model m = s.Model;
foreach (FuncDecl d in m.Decls)
    if (d.DomainSize == 0 && d.Arity == 0)
       Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " -> " + m.ConstInterp(d));
    else 
       Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " -> " + m.FuncInterp(d));
```

However, the code failed on array declarations when it tried to call `ConstInterp`.

> Microsoft.Z3.Z3Exception: Non-zero arity functions and arrays have
>   FunctionInterpretations as a model. Use FuncInterp.

I checked all properties on [Model](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_model.html), but it seems there is none which helps creating correct conditions on array declarations.

How can I fix this? And do I miss any other kinds of declaration as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array constants are an exception in Z3, as they have function interpretations as a model. This is why ConstInterp does not apply and therefore throws an exception. I'm afraid for now the best solution is simply to check the range of the funcdecl, until we get a better solution.

E.g., replace

```
if (d.DomainSize == 0 && d.Arity == 0)
```

with

```
if (d.DomainSize == 0 && d.Arity == 0 && d.Range.SortKind != Z3_ARRAY_SORT)
```